# Undefined variable: errors from empty 3rd uri params (code igniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

I have many controllers with functions like

```
function search($person) {
    if empty($person) {
            redirect('...');
        }
    else {
        .........
    }
}
```

I wasn't getting  Undefined variable errors before, but now i do (if i go to .../search/) without passing a $person. I found i can fix this by doing `function search($person = null)` but i was wondering if there is a "better" way. I am also curious why i wasn't getting errors before (on localhost) but am now.. (on godaddy).

THANKS!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't provide a default value for the argument in this case, `function search($person)` is how the function should be declared if `$person` is indeed a required argument. You **want** this to throw a warning so you can quickly see what's wrong during development.

In production, you simply switch off [error reporting](http://www.php.net/error%20reporting)/[error display](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).
See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/errors.html.

Comment: Well I want this to work like going to  `/search` takes you to the search page and going to `/search/person` takes you to that person's page.. is it okay if i just have errors turned off or is it "bad"

Comment: @mazlix You should use routes to define separate actions for those two actions then. `/search` displays the search page using the search action, `/search/[user]` displays that user's page using some other action. If you want to keep both mixed into a single method, then well, it's not an error to have an empty `$person`, so you should set it to `null` by default. The rule is: activate error reporting during development, fix all errors. Deactivate error reporting in production.

Comment: Okay thanks, I actually want `/search/[term]` to do a search results page but if it happens to be a user then it just does a `redirect('[user]')`.. so is it OK practice for me to have an if ([term]) {... do search results}else{show search page}?

Comment: @mazlix Sorry, not quite understanding what you're asking. I'd expect `/search` to display a search form and `/search/[term]` to display a results page. As such these seem like two different controller actions and should be sorted out as such through routing.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I'd like `search/[term]` to map to a separate controller, could you explain how to do that in the routes. Thanks, sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: @mazlix I'm not really a CodeIgniter user, but I'd start here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html